# Laravel 4 echo "Orignal" float value in Blade

Tags: laravel-4

I save **float** number from input to MySQL.
I put "3.2" and "486.2" then save, in MySQL store as "3.2", "486.2", same as input and this field have type **float**.

But then i call this number from MySQL to Blade in Laravel like:

```
{{ $Item->price }} and {{ $Item->totalPay }}
```

the page show me: **3.2 => 3.2000000476837**
and **486.2 => 486.20001220703**

What is wrong i am was do?
Does this cause by Blade Engine or something?
I try to round() but this seem cannot.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with **float**, specifically with trying to store decimals as a **float** since they cannot properly be represented. You should try using a **decimal** field in your database since you are stocking currency data. Or even better would be to use an **integer** field, saving your numbers as `320` and `48620`, and then doing all calculations as such, and then dividing the value by 100, or formatting the number before you output it.

Comment: Yeah, **decimal** so you do not need to do the conversion for the 'cents'.

Comment: example i need to store two price: 3.23 and 3.2444, what data type should i use?

Answer (score 0):

`{{ $Item->price }}` and `{{ $Item->totalPay }}`

**`{{ number_format($Item->price,5) }}`** and **`{{ number_format($Item->totalPay,5) }}`**

this will show
3.2 => 3.20000 and 486.2 => 486.20001